# Simulation and fitting 3D ellipsoid

Tags: ellipsoids

I would like to simulate ellipsoid fitting.

In the first step I had ellipsoid with centre in 0,0,0 with specific length of axes a, b, c described by eq. $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$ and several vectors $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$. For these vectors I calculated coordinates x, y, z of intersection of ellipsoid and a straight line with a direction vector $v$ as $x = 0 + v_1t, y = 0 + v_2t, z = 0 + v_3t$ and substituted into the equation of ellipsoid.

By this I created several points on ellipsoid surface in specific directions and I could fit ellipsoid based on these points. I used two algorithms [A](http://www.juddzone.com/ALGORITHMS/least_squares_precision_3D_ellipsoid.html), [B](https://github.com/minillinim/ellipsoid/blob/master/ellipsoid.py) and both worked well I mean eigenvalues were the same as a, b, c and eigenvectors were on x, y, z axes resp.

But I had problem when I wanted to simulate the same ellipsoid but rotated by some angel around some axes, for example beta around y axe. Based on this [text](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403126/what-is-the-general-equation-for-rotated-ellipsoid) I used rotation matrix $R_y (\beta)$ so my new coordinates were $x^{´} = xcos\beta + zsin\beta$, $y^{´}=y$, $z^{´}=zcos\beta - xsin\beta$ so I substituted old coordinates in ellipsoid eq. by new ones and by the same way I created dataset of surface points in specific directions.

But when I fitted the rotated ellipsoid the eigenvalues were not a, b, c and eigenvectors were not in y axe and in rotated x and z axes by $\beta$.

And now I do not know if I made some mistake in creating/calculating my dataset or the fitting algorithms did not work.

Can you help me in this problem? Thank you.

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You must have made an error somewhere.  To simulate identifying a rotated ellipsoid, you must first create points on the unrotated ellipsoid, then rotate and shift them under the rotation matrix $R$ and a shift vector $r_0$, thus generating a new set of points.

Now, the original (basic) ellipsoid had the equation

$$ r^T Q_0 r = 1 $$

The image of coordinate vector $r$ is $ r' = R r + r_0 $.  It follows that the equation of the rotated/shifted ellipsoid is

$$ (r' - r_0)^T R Q_0 R^T (r' - r_0) = 1 $$

Let set $Q = R Q_0 R^T $ then the equation is

$$ (r - r_0)^T Q (r - r_0 ) = 1 $$

Note the $3 \times 3$ matrix $Q$ is of the form

$$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} a && d && e \\ d && b && f \\ e && f && c \end{bmatrix} $$

Thus, by multiplying out the above quadratic form, we obtain

$ a (x - x_0)^2 + b (y - y_0)^2 + c (z - z_0)^2 \\+ 2 d (x - x_0)(y - y_0) + 2 e (x - x_0)(z - z_0) + 2 f (y - y_0) (z - z_0) = 1 $

Thus the equation of the ellipsoid is of the form

$$ A x^2 + B y^2 + C z^2 + D x y + E x z + F y z + G x + H y + I z + J = 0 $$

All the points generated by the simulator will satisfy this equation, thus we can write

$$ A x_i^2 + B y_i^2 + C z_i^2 + D x_i y_i + E x_i z_i + F y_i z_i + G x_i + H y_i + I z_i + J = 0 $$

The unknowns here are the constants $A$ through $J$.  So we'll define a vector $\theta$ as follows

$ \theta = [ A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J ]^T $

and we'll define the matrix $\Phi$ to be the $N \times 10$ matrix whose $i$-th row is

$ \Phi_i = \begin{bmatrix}x_i^2 && y_i^2 && z_i^2 && x_i y_i && x_i z_i && y_i z_i && x_i && y_i && z_i && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Now our equations can be written as

$ \Phi \theta = 0 $

This is an $N$ dimensional vector.  To be able to solve for $\theta$, we'll pre-multiply both sides of the equation by $ \Phi^T$, to get

$ \Phi^T \Phi \theta = 0 $

Which is a set of $10$ equation in $10$ unknowns.  To get a non-zero solution, we'll truncate the system of equations, and take the first $9$ equations, thus disregarding the last equation.  Now, using Gauss-Jordan elimination, we can solve the $ 9 \times 10$ system of equations for the the direction of vector $\theta$.

The solution will be of the form $ \theta = t \varphi $

where $\varphi$ is a fixed vector and $ t $ is an arbitrary scalar.

From here, we now have matrix $Q$ correct up to a scaling factor, as follows

$ Q = t \begin{bmatrix} \varphi_1 && \dfrac{1}{2} \varphi_4 && \dfrac{1}{2} \varphi_5 \\ \dfrac{1}{2} \varphi_4 && \varphi_2 && \dfrac{1}{2} \varphi_6 \\
\dfrac{1}{2} \varphi_5 && \dfrac{1}{2} \varphi_6 && \varphi_3 \end{bmatrix} $

But first, from our equation of the rotated/shifted ellipsoid, we have

$$ (r - r_0)^T Q (r - r_0) = 1 $$

which when expanded becomes

$$ r^T Q r + r^T a  + b = 0 $$

where $ a = - 2 Q r_0 $ and $ b = r_0^T Q r_0 - 1  $

It follows that $r_0 = -\dfrac{1}{2} Q^{-1} a $

Now from our identification we have

$ a = t \begin{bmatrix} \varphi_7 && \varphi_8 && \varphi \end{bmatrix} $

Therefore, we can determine the shift vector $r_0$ because the $t$'s cancel out.

Once this is done, we can determine the value of $t$ from

$ b = r_0^T Q r_0 - 1 $

which is linear in $t$.  Then our matrix $Q$ is fully specified.

But we're not done yet, to find the semi-axes of the ellipsoid we have to diagonalize $Q$ into  $ Q = R D R^T $ and this can done using, for example, *MATLAB*, or *Mathematica*.  The diagonal matrix $D$ has on its diagonal the reciprocal of the semi-axes lengths squared, i.e.

$ D = \text{diag}(\dfrac{1}{a^2}, \dfrac{1}{b^2}, \dfrac{1}{c^2} ) $

Hence, using this reverse-engineering process (i.e. identification) we were able to retrieve all the parameters of the original ellipsoid, its rotation matrix, and it shift vector.